# How to get the list of negative words of certain verbs for Yes/No Questions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, lexical-analysis

I have a list of verbs:

```
words_list =['do','does','did','was'...............]
```

I want to get a new list of verbs including all the negative of the above words. For example:

```
negative_words = ["don't","doesn't","didn't","wasn't",.........]
```

Is there any technique in NLTK to do this?

Comment: Most tools do the reverse = don't would become do not.  I think that you would need to write a custom parser to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about NLTK but PyDictionary could help.
https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/
Just do

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary = PyDictionary()
dictionary.getAntonym(word)
```

will result an antonym. It's not exactly what you're looking for but it should help.